# Does wireless traffic from a wireless access point have to go through a router?

Tags: router, home-networking, wireless-access-point

Say that I have a wireless access point connected to a wired router and that there are two computers connected to the access point by wifi.

If those two computers communicate with each other (e.g. I transfer a file from one to another), will the traffic go through the wired router or just through the access point. I.e. does the traffic go Computer 1->access point->wired router->access point->computer 2 **or** Computer 1->access point->computer 2?

(AT&T gave me a 802.11n access point and connected it to a router with 10/100 ethernet ports. I'm curious if the wired connection to the router could *in theory* be the limiting factor between file transfers inside my home network. I realize that *in practice* the wireless speed will likely be the limiting factor, but I'm not asking about that.)

Answer (score 2):

Connections over WiFi are interfered with by the encryption. It is usually NOT possible for two machines connected to one access point to send messages directly to each other (without using the access point). Sometimes the setup of the encryption also disallows communication between two machines connected to an access point via the access point.

If it is allowed the communication will be from machine A to the access point then out to machine B. It will not be via any router further along the network.

So assuming it works the performance of a WiFi connection between two machines is likely to be quite poor because the data is transmitted over the air twice. Putting one of the machines on a wire is likely to improve things a lot. Also with wireless N (and a multi-channel access point) putting the machines at right angles to each other as seen from the access point is likely to give improved performance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wasn't asking about direct Computer 1->Computer 2 communication. However, you answered my question that it's possible to communicate via the access point without going through the router (Computer 1->access point->computer 2). Do you have a citation for this?

Comment: Only in terms of the facts that many of these boxes are Linux based and that's how the Linux bridging (and network routing) code works - copied from everyone else. Simplest proof to you is probably a direct experiment. Once the machines have IP addresses the router can be removed (disconnected) and connections will still be possible between the computers, though you may have to use the IP addresses rather than names. [Link to Linux bridging](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/bridge)